# jquery load to pull specific image

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to use jquery load, to load to a specific image into a div, this is what I have so far, not quite working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

$('#violin_img_1').load('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html', function() {
    $(".violin:first").find('.photo').find('img');
});   


});
```

the div in the .inventory page is structured like so:

```
<div id="bow_cello-VictorFetique_1093" class="iso bow bow_cello instrument_container">
    <div class="about background_notselected">
        <div class="about_txt">
            <div class="about_summary">
                <h3>
                    Price: $15,000
                </h3>
                <br class="spacer">
                <h3>
                        A ﬁne French cello bow branded: Vtor FETIQUE A PARIS, sold with ETIENNE VATELOT certiﬁcate.
                        81 Grams, round reddish brown Pernambuco stick, silver winding, silver mounted ebony frog.   
                </h3>
            </div>
            <h1>
                 Victor Fetique, 1093
            </h1>
            <h2>
                Cello Bow
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img class="inventory_tile_img" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/tiles/inventory_tile.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <img class="instrument" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/instruments/bows/cellos/VictorFetique_1093.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="enlarge bc">
            <img class="enlarged_unselected" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/elements/fullscreen_unselected.png"/>
            <img class="enlarged_selected" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/elements/fullscreen_selected.png"/>
            <div id="VictorFetique_1093" class="enlarged_txt">Enlarge Image</div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `find('.photo")` to `find('.photo')` but `find` will just return the jQ object you search

Comment: hmm, didn't work, I updated the question so be a little more clear

Comment: Yhe double quote ;), like @JonathandeM. said

Comment: yea I changed that, it didn't seem to work, I thought maybe there was something wrong with the way I wrote the load function.

Comment: Yhe double quote ;), like @JonathandeM. said

Comment: seriously?  I just said I changed that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you want to get to that element you should load it like this :

```
$('#violin_img_1').load('http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/inventory.html .violin:first .photo img')
```

Also are you n the same domain ? :

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

[link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: yea, it is the same domain.  SO finding the first div with class violin, then finding the div with the class photo, and then loading the img in that class, I think your post stops a step early?

Comment: hmmm, I cannot figure out for the life of me why this isn't working

Comment: does it matter that it has other classes besides violin?

Comment: No it doesn't. however i can' t seem to find a class named violin, i find composite words with violin like bow_violin... if you want to include those also you can put a wild card [class*=vioilin] instead of  .violin => http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/